# Code refactor, WebStorm - The most efficient way to update the import paths?

Tags: import, path, refactoring, webstorm

I use WebStorm.

I've split a code from a file with interfaces and moved every interface to a separate file.

**What is the most efficient way to update the import paths of these interfaces for each file that uses the interface?**

Currently, I search by an interface name, where it's used, deleted the import and auto import again. It's not a very convenient way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You can cleanly move the interface to a dedicated file by `Refactor` > `Move` option. You can do this by placing a cursor on the interface declaration and hit `F6`.

**Option 2:**
Trigger "Import all unambiguous imports" per file with `Alt` + `Shift` + `Enter`. However, it requires doing `Alt` + `Enter` first if you don't see the below tooltip.

[image]

Comment: Great advise! It works.